# Subadditivity of Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* define an *elementary set* as the finite union of intervals of the form $(a,b)$, $[a,b]$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $[a,a]:=\{a\}$ and $\emptyset$, and define the *Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure* $m_F$ of an *elementary set* as the sum of the $m$ measures of the disjoint sets whose union the *elementary set* is, where $m$ is defined in the following way:$$m(a,b)=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}F(b-h)-\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}F(a+h),\quad m[a,b]=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}F(b+h)-\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}F(a-h)$$ $$m(a,b]=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}F(b+h)-\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}F(a+h),\quad m[a,b)=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}F(b-h)-\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}F(a-h)$$where $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a non decreasing function. I suspect that such limits are intended to exist finite.
Of course if $I$ is an interval then $m_F(I)=m(I)$.

The text says that $m_F$ is subadditive, i.e., for all the elementary sets $A$ and $A_n$ such that $A\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, $m_F(A)\leq\sum_n m_F(A_n)$, and that $m_F$'s subadditivity is proven analolgously to how the subadditivity of the measure $\tilde{m}$ of this [theorem 2](http://librarum.org/book/10022/133).
I cannot adapt this proof to $m_F$ because I cannot see how to find *a closed rectangle* [in our case an interval $[c,d]$] *contained in* $P_j$ [an interval] *of area* [measure] *no less than* $m(P_j)-\varepsilon/(2k)$. I would be able to find such an interval if I knew that for any $\varepsilon>0$ we could "squeeze" $(a,b)$ into intervals $(a+\delta,b)$ and $(a,b-\delta)$ such that $m(a+\delta,b)<\varepsilon$ and $m(a,b-\delta)<\varepsilon$, but the discontinuity of $F$ is an obstacle to me...

I cannot find any proof of the subadditivity of the measure defined in this way anywhere, though it is one of the first topics that the book deal with when discussing the theory of measure. I must stress that the text has introduced no other measure than the Lebesgue measure for rectangles at this point.

I $\infty$-ly thank you for any help!

Comment: A non-decreasing $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$ has finite left- and right- limits at every point because bounded monotone sequences converge. There are at most a countable number of discontinuities on any finite interval because the jumps must sum to a finite number. You can always redefine $F$ to be continuous from the left (right) at every point. Then $F(b)-F(a)=m_{F}[a,b)$. Start by looking only at such intervals and this $F$ first.

Comment: As to redefining $F$ as continuous from the left or right, I see that it implies that $[a,b)$ can be squeezed so that $m[a,b-\delta)<\varepsilon$ and analogously for $(a,b]$. But I didn't know a thing have I correctly understood that a more than countable sum of "jumps" amounts to $+\infty$? How can it be proven? I uncountably thank you! ;-)

Comment: If $j(x)$ is the jump at $x$, then $F(x+\epsilon)-F(x-\epsilon) \ge j(x)$. On a finite interval $[a,b]$, how many jumps of size $1/n$ can you have at most, estimated in terms of $F(b+0)-F(a-0)$?

Comment: Thank you again! Let's call $S_{1/n}$ the set of all jump discontinuities of size $\geq 1/n$. I would say that $S_{1/n}$ contains at most $\lfloor n(\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)-\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)) \rfloor+1$ jump discontinuities of size at least $1/n$. So the set of all the discontinuities, which is $U_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}S_{1/n}$, is countable. Hoping my reasoning isn't wrong...

Comment: Yes. The number of discontinuities in a finite interval [a,b] with jump of size 1/n or larger must be finite. So the total number of discontinuities in the interval of any size is countable; so the total number of discontinuities anywhere on the real line is (at most) countable, too.

Comment: Uncountable thanks! ;-)